# Does this Laplace equation with 2 initial conditions have separable solutions? How about nonseparable?

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, harmonic-functions, laplacian

Let $u: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a function that satisfies

1. Laplace equation $u_{xx}(x,y) + u_{yy}(x,y) = 0$ for $x \in [0,\pi]$ and $y \in [0,1]$
2. $u_{x}(0,y)=0, y \in [0,1]$
3. $u_x(\pi,y)=0, y \in [0,1]$
4. $u(x,0)=a^2 \cos(x), x \in [0,\pi]$, for some $a \ne 0$ (I think $a$ is a real constant)
5. $u(x,1)=a^2 \cos^2(x), x \in [0,\pi]$

**Question 1**: If there exist $F, G:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $u(x,y)=F(x)G(y)$ for all $x \in [0,\pi]$ and $y \in [0,1]$, then what are possible $u$'s?

I don't think there are any because $u(x,0)=a^2 \cos(x) = F(x)G(0)$ and $u(x,1)=a^2 \cos^2(x) = F(x)G(1)$ give us $a^2 \cos^2(x) = F(x)G(0) \cos(x) = F(x)G(1)$. It seems that $F(x)G(0) \cos(x) = F(x)G(1)$ makes sense if and only if $G(0)=G(1)=0$ but then with $a^2 \cos^2(x) = F(x)G(0) \cos(x)$, we would get $a=0$.

Also I've solved $\frac{F''(x)}{F(x)} = \frac{-G''(y)}{G(y)} = -k$ for the cases of $k < 0$, $k = 0$ and $k > 0$, and I think $k<0$ and $k=0$ end up contradicting conditions, so we must have $k>0$. However, I think $k>0$ might have some contradictions too. I don't want to type up what I got for $F$ or $G$ without first resolving the issue in the previous paragraph.

**Question 2**: If there exist $F, G:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $u(x,y)=F(x)G(y)$ for all $x \in [0,\pi]$ and $y \in [0,1]$, then in solving for the possible $u$'s if any, are complex variables needed? I know that for analytic/holomorphic functions $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$, $f(z)=v(x,y)+iw(x,y), z=x+iy$, we have $v$ and $w$ harmonic and thus solutions of Laplace equation, but I don't quite see the relevance here.

**Question 3**: Can someone please provide a reference on obtaining general solutions to this kind of problem with these kinds of conditions?

I believe it begins with considering $u$ as separable into $u=FG$ and then solving for $u$ in general just like with the [heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#math_4) and wave equation and then you get to Fourier series, but I was not able to find anything explicit in Pinchover and Rubinstein (It's been several years since I've read this book. I mostly read heat and wave. I'm learning Laplace for the first time now.) or this [link](http://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/teach/260/laplace.php) that directly and completely helps. In particular, I don't think either the book or the link contain examples for the kinds of conditions above.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81908/separation-of-variables-boundary-value-problem) is the closest kind of problem I've seen on stackexchange. It has $u(x,0)=0$ though. This leads me to suspect such problems might be a little advanced.

---

**Answer**: This question appears to have been answered with the comments below. Please now refer to my new question: [2D Laplace equation with two initial conditions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3476132/2d-laplace-equation-with-two-initial-conditions)

Comment: Note that you should not consider the initial condition when looking for a separable solution, just the boundary conditions. We satisfy the initial condition by taking a linear combination of the (complete set of) separable solutions we find (when they exist).

Comment: @Winther Oh so for $u=FG$, we assume only conditions 1, 2 and 3 but not conditions 4 and 5? Do you have references for this please?

Comment: See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations for an example (I'm assuming here that by "separable solutions" what you really are asking about is how to do separation of variables for solving PDEs. If the question is *literally* if the full solution is on the form $u(x,y) = F(x)G(y)$ then you have solved it correctly)

Comment: @Winther I know the general idea of how to solve PDEs assuming $u(x,y)=F(x)G(y)$. I learned heat and wave equation years ago, but I'm learning Laplace for the first time now. So far it doesn't seem different in approach. I just encountered this problem in a past paper for an undergraduate class that kind of crams PDEs, Fourier, Calculus II and Calculus III all in one course. It actually just says 'Find the solution u(x,y) by separation of variables.'

Comment: @Winther Based on Wikipedia (not only the link you provided but also [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Solving_the_heat_equation_using_Fourier_series)) and what little I remember from my learnings of the heat and wave equation years ago, my understanding is that when solving heat/wave/Laplace, one first solves for the case when $u=FG$ and next solves for general $u$. Do I understand and remember correctly? In that case, for the initial step of $u=FG$, conditions 4 and 5 are excluded?

Comment: Ok then what I said above holds. Its exactly the same for Laplace as for any other linear PDE. First find the most general solution to the two ODEs you get. Use the boundary conditions to fix some of the free parameters (and determine the allowed values of the separation constant - you will likely find that it has to be an integer or similar). This will give you a set of countable solutions $u_n(x,y)$. The most general solution is a linear combination of this $u(x,y) = \sum c_n u_n(x,y)$. Fix the coefficients $c_n$ by applying the initial condition(s).

Comment: @Paul $u_{xx}$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+d%2Fdx+%281-y%29%5Ccos%7B%28x%29%7D%2By%5Ccos%5E2%7B%28x%29%7D%2C), $u_{yy}$ [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdy+d%2Fdy+%281-y%29%5Ccos%7B%28x%29%7D%2By%5Ccos%5E2%7B%28x%29%7D%2C). So $u_{xx} = u_{yy} = 0$ ?

Comment: @Winther Thanks! Which are boundary, and which are initial please?

Comment: When I said initial conditions above I meant the last two (though all conditions are kind of boundary conditions here).

Comment: @Winther Ok thanks. I'll get back to you on this. I actually got $k$ to be square of a positive integer $n$ (so $k=n^2$ for $n=1,2,3,...$, yielding the countable solutions) without yet using conditions 4 and 5 and then I always run into a problem whenever I multiply by $\cos(x)$ to use conditions 4 and 5. Okay good to know I was indeed onto something.

Comment: @Winther I tried it, and I don't see how solutions exist unless $u(x,1)$ is meant t be $u_y(x,1)$. Can you provide a textbook or reference for solving a 2D Laplace PDE problem with 2 equations for initial conditions $u(x,l)=f(x)$ and $u(x,L)=g(x)$ and 2 for homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions $u_x(r,y)=0=u_x(R,y)$ for $r \le x \le R$ and $l \le y \le L$ where we really have $u(x,L)=g(x)$ and not $u_y(x,L)=g(x)$? The closest I could find was [Pinchover and Rubinstein Exercise 7.12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZGpW.png)

Comment: @Winther I asked a new question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3476132/)

Comment: @Winther in general (not just for Laplace), how do I know which conditions go with the initial step of $u=FG$? In this case, conditions 2 and 3 go with $u=FG$ but conditions 4 and 5 don't. Based on my recent revision, it appears, everything homogeneous goes with the $u=FG$ even if it's an initial condition. Not really sure. Wikipedia doesn't seem to have any examples with 2 initial conditions that really are of the form $u(x,\cdot)=f(x)$,  $u(x,\cdot)=g(x)$ and not that one is  $u(x,\cdot)=f(x)$ while the other is  $u_y(x,\cdot)=g(x)$

Comment: @Winther Note: Both $f$ and $g$ are not identically zero